# JIRA - documentation of searchrequest.xml

Tags: documentation, jira

My BSc thesis is a JIRA gadget that uses `searchrequest.xml` strongly.

I use this feauture through observations collected from different pages:

- e.g.
  http://pulasthisupun.blogspot.fi/2011/03/retrieving-and-filtering-jira-issue.html

and from source code of other gadgets.

Is there any official documentation available about this feature?

Answer (score 1):

There is some documentation about this at 
https://developer.atlassian.com/display/JIRADEV/Search+Request+View+Plugin+Module
but most of the parameters are passed as a JQL statement now